# Cookies set during an AJAX request valid also for subsequent (non AJAX) requests?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, cookies

I'm using AngularJS and during a post on the server side I'm sending a cookie back in the response. 
Will this cookie be used for subsequent requests (on the same domain/host) also for NON ajax calls?

Comment: How did you save your cookie?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular Js $cookies have a lot of option for use cookies;

```
$cookies.put('key', 'value',[options]);
```

In $cookiesProvider you can use these;

- **path** - {string} // This is for you
- **domain** - {string} // This is for you
- **expires** - {string|Date}
- **secure** - {boolean}

For more info ; [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies), [$cookiesProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider)

Comment: thank you for your quick explaination. But this means that I still have to code something. 
I thought the browser will store this cookie and sent it for the subsequent requests without any custom code